# Fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have main layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_showdetails"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Show Details" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:id="@+id/my_parent_layout"
    >
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

am trying to call another activity in the my_parent_layout using this class 
package com.appnetics;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmenttestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Button LogIn = null ;
    final   FragmentManager fragmentManager =    getSupportFragmentManager()  ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_showdetails); 
        LogInEvent() ; 
    }
public void LogInEvent(){

        LogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        details fragment = new details();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.my_parent_layout, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        }); 

    }


}
```

the details layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:text="time_label"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_view_time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32dp"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout code is 
/* $Id: $
 */

```
package com.appnetics;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;




/**
 * DateTime
 */
public class details extends Fragment {
    private static String getDateTimeString(Date time) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            .format(time);
    }

    private final String time = getDateTimeString(new Date());

    /** @see android.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle b)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.details,
            container,
            false);  //!!! this is important

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_view_time))
            .setText(time);

        return view;
    }
}
```

the problem is that when click the button, nothing appear , any idea what's wrong in my code

Comment: Have you tried : fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.my_parent_layout, fragment)

Comment: Are you inflating the view in your details fragment?

Comment: @Tarun yes I want to inflat it

Comment: did my answer solved your problem? it looks like you edit something.

Comment: I will try it today and will tell you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start!

On your details XML:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_time_label"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date_time_label"
```

this two tags are for relative layouts, the parent of the layouts must be of relative type in order to work.

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

This tag is also incorrect, if you want to center the text in the textview you can use two ways or wrap content in textView and set center in its parent or use:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:width="fill_parent"
```

This will be the detail_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="time_label"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_view_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="view time"
    android:textSize="32dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On your main.xml you declare the schema lots of times! should be declared once on your root layout.

```
 LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

So the main.xml will be...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment is an element that is declared in its class and apply its xml.

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
}
```

And in the main activity add it to the holder layout:

```
public class FragmentSimpleTestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Button addFragment;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    addFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_fragment);

    addFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_holder,fragment, "MY_FRAG");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Its important that fragmentTransaction.add has parameters

1: the id of the view to hold the fragment.
2: the fragment object.
3: a tag that is used to find the fragments in the stack.

and thats all :)

Enjoy your fragments! you can also set animations when adding or removing it.

Comment: how to remove all the fragments please

Comment: sorry @AMH you can remove fragments from the stack with popBackStack(java.lang.String, int) its on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html documentation.

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView()

> The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you
>   must return a View from this method that is the root of your
>   fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not
>   provide a UI.

Call OnCreateView in your fragment class

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when fragment wasn't showing up. The problem was that I removed AndroidAnnotations, but forgot to move the code from onViewCreated and onCreate methods to the onCreateView. I found this mistake by comparing the code of two fragments - one, that was showing up and the other that wasn't. So, if you have similar problems, try to check the code of fragments. It may not show any errors at first glance, but will not still work or show up because of those errors.

Particularly, check that you have this method and that you inflate a view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    return v;

}
```